# IF Statement in Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, designer-workflow

I'm hoping this is a simple question but it's been a while since I touched SharePoint.

I'm building out a simple InfoPath form that users will use for an escalation process.

I need to build a workflow in the back-end list that does the following:

Sends an email to a Pre-Determined distribution list, this distro list should change depending on a drop-down menu value in the InfoPath.

Is there a way to create an IF statement inside workflow to do the following?

```
if(choice = drop down menu value 1, send to DL 1, etc etc)
```

Or would I need to create a separate reference list containing the DistoLists and their matching dropdown values and reference that?

Comment: What do you mean with "send to DL 1 " ? are you need to add or update item with this value

Answer (score 1):

Use IF condition in sharepoint designer Workflow .

- Create a List workflow for the particular list.In workflow two IF conditions are available as below

  1. If value equals value
  2. If field equals value

Use If field(your dropdown) equals value

Reference Link 
[Workfow Conditions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Workflow-conditions-in-SharePoint-Designer-2010-A-quick-reference-guide-d8e33ac7-9336-487f-a60b-388c4ea497ff)

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly, if I have multiple selections by using a checkbox however how can I get the workflow to recognize multiple entries on the same list item?

Comment: Based on your requirement choose the If condtion "Contains" stringe.Log your multiselection field in workflow histrory and see the result . Based on result split string value into single and do your condition check